# A question on minimizing distance function

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $C:I\to \Bbb R^2$ be a continuous and non-differentiable curve and $p=(x,y)$ a point on  $\Bbb R^2$. Is the $d(p,C)$ (distance from $C$) a differentiable function? I think this function is not differentiable. but how to calculate  $d(p,C)$ for given $p$?

Comment: Even if $C$ is differentiable, the function you describe is not differentiable.

Comment: This question needs some significant improvement. In particular what do you mean by "how to minimize d(p,C) for given p"? By your own definition $d(p,C)$ is not a function, but a number defined by the minimal distance from the curve to $p$. Perhaps you meant to ask how to calculate $d(p,C)$ given that the curve is not differentiable? In that case we certainly need to know more about $C$ and what your specific needs are regarding such a computation.

Comment: Ohhh. sorry, Yes I  asked how to calculate $d(p,C)$ given that the curve is not differentiable?

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to improve the question, but I'm afraid your edit has not fixed the confusion. $d(p,C)$ is not a function but a number. The function which you seem to be concerned with is the one implicitly defined in the first sentence of the answer by Mundron Schmidt. I am specifically referring to the sentence "Is the d(p,C) (distance from C) a differentiable function"

Comment: $d(p,C)$ is a function depend on $p$.

Comment: @C.F.G, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is not differentiable, then $t\mapsto dist(p,C(t))$ is in general not differentiable.

How you can find the distance from $C$ to $p$ depends on $C$. Is $C$ piecewise differentiable? If so, then you can compute the minimal distance on each piece and compare them. But don't forget the boundary for each piece!

Comment: and if $C$ is not piecewise differentiable?

Comment: Then you might need numerical tools. Without further information about $C$ it is not easy to answer...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C\equiv(0,0)$. Then $d(p,C) = \|p\|$ is not differentiable. What do you mean by "minimize $d(p,C)$ for given $p$"? Is $p$ fixed?

Comment: It seems that regarding the question of differentiability $p$ is not considered to be fixed.

Comment: For your particular example the function is only non-differentiable at $p=0$. I think your answer would be improved by providing this context.